# VueJS add/remove class to <html> tag

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs3

I am working on creating themes in VueJS right now. I have a themes.less file that executes a function upon change of `<html>` tag class. I want to be able to programmatically swap the theme based on selected option in a dropdown. When the dropdown is set to 'Dark' I want the .dark class added to my `<html>` tag. So far, I have not found a way to manipulate the root `<html>` tag from VueJS. Is it possible to add and remove classes from this tag without adding JQuery to the project?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible to add and remove classes from this tag without adding JQuery to the project?

You can use pure JavaScript.

```
document.documentElement.classList.add("MyClass");
document.documentElement.classList.remove("MyClass");
```

or

```
document.querySelector('html').classList.add("MyClass");
document.querySelector('html').classList.remove("MyClass");
```

If you want to use the body instead of html tag:

```
document.body.classList.add("MyClass");
document.body.classList.remove("MyClass");
```

or

```
document.querySelector('body').classList.add("MyClass");
document.querySelector('body').classList.remove("MyClass");
```

The only reason this is acceptable in VueJS, is because the HTML and BODY tag are outside of the template of VueJS thus wouldn't conflict with the framework.